# AddEventListener doesn't work on newly added innerHtml?

Tags: javascript, onclick

There are so many questions on this problem , all of them cover different situations. None help me in this situation.

**1.I am not adding the click listener before the element is "created"**,

**2. I am not calling the callback in on event method(instead I pass it in a higher order fashion)**

**3. The num is always correct**

```
 this.update = function(data,status,num){
        var raceview = document.getElementById("raceview")
    if(status == "domestic"){
        raceview.innerHTML += `<div class="race">
                                <img id="raceprofileimg" src="${data.image}" alt="">
                                <h3 id ="pendingmessage">Race is Pending</h3>
                                <h3 id = "username" class="racenames">${data.name}</h3>
                              </div>`

        
    }
    else if (status == "pending"){ //both parties accepted the race
        raceview.innerHTML += `<div class="race">
            <img id="raceprofileimg" src="${data.image}" alt="">
            <h3 id="name${num}" class="racenames">${data.name}</h3>
            <button id="${num}" class="racebuttons" type="button">Won</button>
            <button  id="${num}"class="rejectbuttons" type="button">Loss</button>   
        </div>`


    }
    else{
    
            raceview.innerHTML += `<div class="race">
                    <img id="raceprofileimg" src="${data.image}" alt="">
                    <h3 id="name${num}" class="racenames">${data.name}</h3>
                    <button id="race${num}"  class="racebuttons" type="button">Race</button>
                    <button id="reject${num}"  class="rejectbuttons" type="button">Reject</button>  
                              </div>`
        

            document.getElementById("race"+num).addEventListener("click",function(){self.accept_race(num,data.name)})               
    }


    
    
        

}
```

**Generated Html:**

[image]

Comment: I guess the buttons show up? I tried to reproduce it in my console, but there it fires. Did you declare `self` before? Or should it be `this`?

Comment: This function is nested deep inside of a bunch of call backs and lambdas (thats the reason for using the self reference). var self = this;    calling the function by itself works 100% of the time. So I don't believe there is an issue with the self functionality. since self.accept_race() works fine. @JosefWittmann

Comment: Then I need more context... Can you provide a link to the code?

Comment: @JosefWittmann I added more information for understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `raceview.innerHTML +=` you overwrite all DOM elements in `raceview`. They lose all event binding, because the whole `raceview` element gets rebuilt.

The last button should work, I guess.

You could solve it like this:

```js
const race = document.createElement("div");
race.classList.add("race");
raceview.appendChild(race);

race.innerHTML = `...`;

document
  .getElementById("race" + num)
  .addEventListener("click", /* your handler */);
```

Comment: Easy to understand , Thanks for your insight. This answered my question.

Comment: You're welcome. For your next project you might want to consider view libraries like React or Vue, since they simplify the process of creating elements in JS greatly.